# Subset/Slice dask array using boolean array of lower dimension

Tags: python, numpy, dask

Using `numpy` I can subset a 3D array using a 2D 'mask'. The same returns an `IndexError` with dask arrays. Is there any way to reproduce that `numpy` behaviour below using `dask`?

```py
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da

# Create 3d arrays of random values and mask with shape matching second and third dimensions
y_da = da.random.random(size=(20, 100, 100))
y_np = np.random.rand(20, 100, 100)
mask = np.zeros((100, 100), dtype=np.uint8)
mask[20:80, 3:77] = 1

# Apply mask (flattens axes 1 and 2)
print(y_np[:,mask == 1].shape) # OK
print(y_da[:,mask == 1].shape) # IndexError
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [204]: y_np = np.random.rand(20, 100, 100)
     ...: mask = np.zeros((100, 100), dtype=np.uint8)
     ...: mask[20:80, 3:77] = 1
In [205]: y_np.shape
Out[205]: (20, 100, 100)
In [206]: mask.shape
Out[206]: (100, 100)
In [207]: y_np[:,mask == 1].shape
Out[207]: (20, 4440)
```

In `numpy`, using a boolean mask is, in general, the equivalent of using the corresponding 'advanced indexing' arrays.  Thus:

```
In [208]: I,J=np.nonzero(mask==1)
In [209]: I.shape
Out[209]: (4440,)
In [210]: y_np[:,I,J].shape
Out[210]: (20, 4440)
```

See the boolean indexing section of the basic indexing docs:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing

You might be able to apply the same idea to `dask`.

I have to 'split' the `nonzero` results with `I,J`, otherwise:

```
In [211]: y_np[:,np.nonzero(mask==1)].shape
Out[211]: (20, 2, 4440, 100)

In [213]: y_np[(slice(None),*np.nonzero(mask==1))].shape
Out[213]: (20, 4440)
```